# Pass input value through react-redux action payload?

Tags: react-redux

```
export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.props.onSearchTermChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSearchTermChange: () =>
      dispatch({
        type: "SEARCHTERMCHANGE",
        payLoad: {}
      })
  };
};
```

Basically when the input changes i want to call the "onSearchTermChange" action and pass the value of the input to a reducer, but I don't know how to access the input value from the the action onSearchTermChange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to use `event.target.value`

```
<input 
  onChange={ (e) => this.props.onSearchTermChange(e.target.value)} 
  value={this.props.value} 
/>
```

your action creator will be now

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSearchTermChange: (value) =>
      dispatch({
        type: "SEARCHTERMCHANGE",
        payLoad: value
      })
  };
};
```

and your reducer

```
case "SEARCHTERMCHANGE":
  return {
    ...state,
    value: action.payLoad
  }
```

finally you need to import your value to your props.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   value: state.value,
})
```