# Retrieve data from input and pass to redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Simple todo app -
I need to retrieve my input value from my container/component and store it in redux state.  The input value is being stored in local state until until the user hits the "add" button.

My problem is :
How do I pass this input value up through the dispatch/action and then retrieve it for my reducer to handle it.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...state
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addTodo: () => dispatch(addTodo())
})


class Main extends React.Component {

    state = {
        input: ''
    }

    handleInputChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            input: e.target.value
        })
    }

    addTodo = (e) => {
        this.props.addTodo(this.state.input);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className='Main'>

                <div className='head'>
                    <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} type="text"/>
                    <button onClick={this.addTodo}>Add</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Here is the action:

```
export const addTodo = () => dispatch => {

    dispatch({
     type: 'ADD_TODO',
     payload
    })

}
```

Here is the reducer:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
     case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
       result: action.payload
      }
     default:
      return state
    }

}
```

I'm just lost on how to move this data to manipulate it with my reducer.

Comment: You can find an example in the redux documentation: https://redux.js.org/basics/example

Comment: Follow the examples in the link provided by Harald.
Your action will pass the data to your reducer when it is called. Your reducer will listen for the correct action.type. When the correct action.type has been dispatched the data will be in the reducer and run through your logic before being put to the redux store

Comment: It looks like you've set up everything correctly on your component. How does your action and reducer code look?

Comment: I've added those

Comment: this answer was super helpful to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593411/pass-input-value-through-react-redux-action-payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently not actually passing your input value to the action.

You need to change both the action creator and the `mapDispatchToProps` function to the following:

```
export const addTodo = (payload) => dispatch => {

    dispatch({
     type: 'ADD_TODO',
     payload
    })

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addTodo: (input) => dispatch(addTodo(input))
})
```