# Sending event.target.value as parameter to dispatched action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to update my store's "searchField" value (it starts as a blank string) when a user inputs a value into the text box of the free-response component. When I type in the field, the "searchField" property becomes undefined and I fear it's a fundamental error I can't see (I'm still quite new to Redux.) I've included my reducer, component and relevant action code below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

free-response.component.jsx:

```
export const FreeResponse = ({searchField,changeSearchField,i}) =>{
  let questionURL="/images/question";

  return(
    <div className="main">
      <img src={`${questionURL}${i}.png`}/>

      <form >
        <input type="text" onChange={changeSearchField} value={changeSearchField} alt="text field"/>
      </form>
    </div>
)}

const mapStateToProps=state=>({
  searchField: state.question.searchField,
  i:state.question.i
})

const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>({
  changeSearchField: (e)=>dispatch(changeSearchField(e.target.value))
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(FreeResponse);
```

question.reducer.js:

```
    return{
      ...state,
      searchField:changeSearchField(e)
    };
```

question.utils.js (action creator):

```
export const changeSearchField=(e)=> e;
```

question.actions.js:

```
export const changeSearchField=()=>({
  type:QuestionActionTypes.CHANGE_SEARCHFIELD,

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you did not define the payload for your `changeSearchField` action. This is to ensure that the values from your form input will be passed on by the action creator.

This is one way you can do it:

```
export const changeSearchField = (searchField) => ({
  type: QuestionActionTypes.CHANGE_SEARCHFIELD,
  payload: searchField
});
```

And on your reducer, you just need to update the store with the values from the payload (the below may differ depending on the actual structure of your store):

```
return {
  ...state,
  searchField: action.payload.searchField,
};
```

Comment: I tried the above and still had the same outcome, although I don't believe my reducer is set up to receive your answer. Is the parameter you put into the changeSearchField action the value "e.target.value" from the component? I also tried payload:searchField in the action and also to no avail.

Comment: I found the answer here (credit to @Prasanna) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593411/pass-input-value-through-react-redux-action-payload) Is this similar to what you were saying?

Comment: @jmath412 Yes it is, let me update my answer!! Sorry, I guess I wasn't too clear earlier on :)

Comment: Ahh, no I'm sure I was a bit off in my question lol! Thank you so much!